# Refactoring methods that build a Map in Java 8 for integration tests - opportunity for functional programming?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, hashmap, currying

I have code that I'm using to build Map contents for integration tests, and it looks like I should be able to reduce the duplication of the code below with functional programming. (I'm using Java 8.) However, I'm a little rusty, so it's not immediately obvious to me how to refactor this.

In the methods below, the only difference between each consecutive method is that the subsequent method is adding more content to the Map. It looks like I might be able to use currying, but I haven't done that in Java before.

How can I refactor this with functional programming in Java to reduce my duplication?

```
public HashMap<String,String> setupProductsUid() throws Exception {
    OutputMessage actual = statusUpdaterTest.getOutputMessageWithUidOfNewProductsNode();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("replaceThisProductsUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getUid());
    return map;

}
public HashMap<String,String> setupProductsAndProductUid() throws Exception {
    OutputMessage actual = statusUpdaterTest.getOutputMessageWithUidOfNewProductsNode();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("replaceThisProductsUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisProductUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getUid());
    return map;

}
public HashMap<String,String> setupProductsAndProductAndOptionsUid() throws Exception {
    OutputMessage actual = statusUpdaterTest.getOutputMessageWithUidOfNewProductsNode();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("replaceThisProductsUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisProductUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisOptionUid1", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getOptions().get(0).getUid());
    return map;

}
public HashMap<String,String> setupProductsAndProductAndOptionsMultipleUids() throws Exception {
    OutputMessage actual = statusUpdaterTest.getOutputMessageWithUidOfNewProductsNode();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("replaceThisProductsUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisProductUid", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisOptionUid1", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getOptions().get(0).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisOptionUid2", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getOptions().get(1).getUid());
    map.put("replaceThisOptionUid3", actual.getQuery().get(0).getProducts().get(0).getOptions().get(2).getUid());
    return map;
}
```

**Edit:** 
To provide some context, OutputMessage is a deserialized representation of a JSON data response from Dgraph.
The data coming back from Dgraph looks like this:

```
{
    "uid": "0x2938",
    "collectionId": 1,
    "products": [
      {
        "uid": "0x345",
        "productId": 19610626,
        "options": [
          {
            "uid": "0x45256",
            "optionId": 32661491,
            "datetime": "2018-10-31T10:19:32.242",
            "expected": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I have no way to prevent Dgraph from creating arrays for single-object parent-child relationships. It's just the way they have architected the node-edge structure in their graph.

**Edit 2:** 
These functions are getting called by a method that substitutes the keys for the values in the map in test JSON data. The reason for the substitution is that I need a way to obtain UIDs from Dgraph (because the IDs are managed by Dgraph, so I need to query Dgraph after creating the Dgraph nodes in order to find out what UIDs Dgraph will give me for the nodes).

Here's the method that replaces placeholders in the JSON data:

```
public String updateIncomingJsonByReplacingMapValues(HashMap<String, String> map, String incomingJsonWithoutUids) {
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        incomingJsonWithoutUids = incomingJsonWithoutUids.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return incomingJsonWithoutUids;
}
```

Here's an example of a test method that calls the function that replaces placeholders with test data:

```
@Test
public void incomingJsonIsEmptyProductsCollectionWithOnlyProductsUid() throws Exception{
    HashMap<String,String> map = setupProductsUid();
    String incomingJsonWithoutUids = statusUpdaterTest.readTestFile("dgraph_writer_test/02_empty_products_node_in_dgraph.json");

    // Update placeholders with Uid's
    String updatedJson = updateIncomingJsonByReplacingMapValues(map, incomingJsonWithoutUids);
    // Then, write the updated Json to Dgraph and check that the returned UIDs are as expected.
    DgraphClient dgraphClient = statusUpdaterTest.createDgraphClient(false);
    Map<String, String> uidMap = mutate(dgraphClient, updatedJson);
    Assert.assertNotNull(uidMap);
    Assert.assertTrue(uidMap.isEmpty());
}
```

The file `"dgraph_writer_test/02_empty_products_node_in_dgraph.json"` contains this data:

```
{
    "uid": "replaceThisProductsUid",
    "collectionId": 1,
    "products": [
    ]
}
```

Other JSON examples have a lot more data than this one.

Comment: Could we have a bit more context about what the `OutputMessage` is supposed to look like and why we're calling a method on some class called `test` inside a unit test? It looks like there may be a better way of managing this data.

Comment: @Nicko I added some additional context.

Comment: What do the methods which call this look like? These look like they're testing more than a single unit of functionality. Have you considered parsing the JSON result data into a "Collection" domain object so you're not letting the Dgraph JSON accessors like `get(0)` bleed into the rest of your program?

Comment: @Nicko Behold, I have updated the post to answer your question.  :)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance if I've missed something, but shouldn't Dgraph be mocked here for unit tests? Otherwise it looks like you're jumping through a lot of hoops to  test Dgraph, which the Dgraph team has probably already done :) If this is supposed to be an integration test then would it be simpler to just spool up a Dgraph cluster in a docker container, push the data you want to test in and test your `mutate` method on that?

Comment: @Nicko You're right. This is intended for integration tests, rather than unit tests. I have edited my description.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to produce `Map` instances from the individial methods and combine these for example like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static public Map<String, String> merge(Map<String, String>... maps) {
    Map<String, String> mergedMap = Arrays.stream(maps)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
    return mergedMap;
}

@Test
public void thatMapsAreMerged() {
    Map<String, String> map1 = ImmutableMap.of("key one", "value one");
    Map<String, String> map2 = ImmutableMap.of("key two", "value two");

    Map<String, String> expectedMergedMap = ImmutableMap.of("key one", "value one", "key two", "value two");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> actualMergedMap = merge(map1, map2);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedMergedMap, actualMergedMap);
}
```